# How to reset Google reCaptcha?

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

**Here is my PHP Code:**

```
    function post_captcha($user_response) {
    $fields_string = '';
    $fields = array(
        'secret' => '',
        'response' => $user_response
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($result, true);
}
$res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
if (!$res['success']) {
      die('MF005');
} else {
if ($mail->send()) { 
$send_arEmail = $autoresponder->Send();
}}
```

**and here is my JavaScript code:**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script>
function onSubmit(token) {
    document.getElementById("i-recaptcha").submit();
}
</script>
```

**This is my captcha:**

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="" ></div>
```

**and this is button submit:**

```
<button class="button rounded" type="submit" data-callback="onSubmit">Send</button>
```

**This is also my form id:**

```
<form id="i-recaptcha">
```

This above function is working, but after submit form, still captcha is checked, I want to reset it to unchecked once user click on submit button.

Answer (score 37):

You can use it like this. It's based on version.

**Version 3**

```
grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('SITE_KEY', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token){
        $('#token').val(token);
    });
});
```

**Version 2**

```
grecaptcha.reset();
```

**Version 1**

```
Recaptcha.reload();
```

Comment: I've added these two JavaScriptbut it doesnt work. How can I add it?

Comment: which versoin are you using?

Comment: I don't know which version, you can see my above codes. please give me a solution for this. Thank you

Comment: How to do this in version 3?

Comment: @Zam85 I think this grecaptcha.reset(); can work for you.

Comment: @Zam85 Please visit this https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#blocked_frame for more information about v2 vs v3.